# mv file to smb failed, space still used, file missing

Tags: samba, data-recovery, data-loss

I attempted to mv a 14GB file from my local filesystem to a smb share on my windows system.
The mv failed and, after checking `ls` and `df`, the file doesn't appear in the index, yet the space is still taken.

I don't really care about this file, as it was only a backup tar that can be recreated, so my goal is to get rid of the file entirely. `lsof|grep` did not return anything for the file. extundelete wouldn't install properly, so I'm running out of ideas.

I'm limited to a 60GB hdd on a laptop with only 30% left so I don't have many options as far as extracting lost files from the filesystem. I just want to get rid of the file now (it was in the home path ~/). Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you restart both devices and then look for them again?  What is the format of the source drive in question (I assume `ext4` from your remarks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the file is marked as deleted but still held open by the SMB client process - the space won't be reclaimed until all open file handles are closed. You could try unmounting the SMB share to see if that releases the disk space, or restarting the computer for same.